# Is there a way to display some content fields in a separate block?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, entities, blocks

I would like to display some content fields in a separate block so that I can manage the position of these like other blocks and also put them near to other blocks such as the search widget.

I am using display suite for laying out the content but don't think that this will serve my requirement to position some content fields further away from the the main content. One specific example I have is displaying the content's taxonomy fields below the search widget (which is in a block).

Comment: Block reference 
and
node reference might be options to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no! Please no Field Blocks or CCK Blocks or Views. Just use Display Suite and enable the "Display Suite Extras" module so that you can create DS Regions. With DS Regions it's possible to create a new region which is exposed as a block.

Comment: I will give a +1 (and maybe change accepted answer to yours), if you have a link to a guide or point me to where I would turn this on - e.g. in the 'manage display' section for the content type? (I already have display suite extras enabled but can not see how I can use it to make some fields appear in a separate block so that I can control this separate block in admin/structure/blocks )

Comment: Found the answer - to turn on "region to block"  go to yoursite.com/admin/structure/ds/list/extras Then click the bottom tab 'other disabled' and check the 'region to block' check box and go from there. (where yoursite.com is your site - replace this with that)

Comment: This screencast is from the maintainer of Display Suite (swentel) – http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4wyjxyhbNA

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view which selects the field you want from a node. Use contextual filters to get the Node Id in your view.

Comment: +1 thanks @Lance. I think Field as Block in another answer is what I will go for at the moment but thanks for your answer as it may be useful for other scenario and if I have needs beyond what Field as Block provides.

Answer (score 2):

[Field as Block](http://drupal.org/project/fieldblock) is a really simple module that lets you display fields in blocks.

Beyond that, you may want to investigate [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) (and related modules) which is a much more powerful but also much more complicated solution.

Comment: I enabled the module but can't see the 'display as block' option in the managedisplay. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry @pjcdawkins I had to move from your accepted answer to yannickoo as display suite module does what I am looking for and more. Display suite apparently includes the same kind of fuctionality as field as block Also, I am already using display suite and this appears to be incompatible with field as block and given that display suite does this functionality anyway I have chosen that. See issue here: https://drupal.org/node/2032195#comment-7604303 However in consolation I have upvoted some of your other posts.