# How to split node fields into view blocks

Tags: 7, views, theming

I am using Omega, and I want to assign fields for a node type to regions of a template.  I created a view, with a page (to get a URL) and block views with fields. I then assigned the blocks of fields to their regions to only display for that node type.  It's not working.  I have a contextual filter for NID, and if not found, to default to the Content ID in the URL.

I feel like this should work, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77997/is-there-a-way-to-display-some-content-fields-in-a-separate-block/78018#78018).

Comment: The problem with Display Suite is it won't be handled for responsive display, as it only renders in the content region.  I was wanting to take advantage of the Omega template since it will handle the responsive aspect for me.  I need a 70/30 2-column, with 4 horizontal blocks below (like Omega's default template).  How can I do this with Display Suite?

Comment: I just watched the video.  That's exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: But I'd still like to know how to do it in Views.